# how to install hplip 3.17.11?

Tags: 17.10, hplip, 18.04

I found myself with problems of my printer install under ubuntu 17.10 with hplip-3.17.7, which is included standard in 17.10

my printer didn't need an hplip update, but hp advices hplip-3.17.11 as it has added support for ubuntu 17.10

https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/release_notes.

i'm not sure if the upgrade solved the issue or if the reinstall of hplip itself fixed my issue, but this is how i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

this is what did i to, a lot of steps so i'm just gonna say step by step:

1) installed fresh install from ubuntu 17.10:

```
# sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

2) removed all references (so far i knew to find them) from /etc/cups
   basically sudo-ed and cleaned the entire folder out.

3) auto-removed hplip-gui

```
# sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove hplip-gui
```

4) somewhere here i was asked to partially updated ubuntu, which afterwards showed that it became a development version of 18.04
unfortunately i'm not sure if that was induced or just happened, and also don't know it that matters or how to find out.

5)  auto-removed hplip

```
# sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove hplip
```

6) downloaded hplip-3.17.11 from hp site

7) installed hplip-3.17.11 following the installation notes from hp side

8) payed special attention to the installation notes at the beginning of the install.. and did them as such.

8a) software and updates: made sure it was on main-server
8b) locked the cd-rom by:

```
# eject -i 1
```

9) installed hplip-3.17.11

```
# cd desktop
# sh hplip-3.17.11.run
```

no dependency problems at all!

10) installed printer during install via gui

so:

- now printer seems to be properly set-up, for now at least
- no communication error 5012,
- setup via wifi
- unfortunately not found by xsane but i'll look into that later.

update:

i do got a
- unsupported platform warning when running hp-doctor under 18.04
- i did completely fresh install 17.10 (from usb drive) and no error msg now.

maybe try without the (partial) update to 18.04